# Automatic addition of the class "expired" at the expiration of each subsequent day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a calendar for HTML & CSS but I do not have enough JS (or jQuery) so that after a certain time, the dates become inactive. All inactive buttons (with dates) have the class "expired" and it is necessary for me that after the expiration of each day, the class "expired" is added to each next button.

The calendar itself is here:
https://coralife.cf/calendar/

```
<table class="col-12 calendar row justify-content-center">
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <tr class="head-of-calendar">
    <th class="tg-kt03">Пн</th>
    <th class="tg-kt03">Вт</th>
    <th class="tg-kt03">Ср</th>
    <th class="tg-kt03">Чт</th>
    <th class="tg-kt03">Пт</th>
    <th class="tg-kt03">Сб</th>
    <th class="tg-kt03">Вс</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">1</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">2</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">3</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">4</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">5</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">6</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">7</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">8</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num-mini num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">9</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">10</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">11</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">12</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">13</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">14</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">15</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">16</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">17</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">18</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Выбирете другой день"><button class="btn calendar-num num expired" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">19</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Сегодня 20 июля. День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num active" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">20</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">21</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">22</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">23</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">24</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">25</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">26</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">27</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">28</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">29</button></td>
    <td class="tg-i6c6" data-toggle="tooltip" title="День свободен!"><button class="btn calendar-num num" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">30</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, here the calendar: https://coralife.cf/%D1%81alendar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following script tag at the bottom of your page :

```
<script>
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("num");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  let btn = btns[i];
  if (parseInt(btn.textContent) < new Date().getDate()){
    btn.classList.add("expired");
  }
}
</script>
```

I have made an example here where I add also the disabled attribute: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bXdraG

Comment: Hmmm. This code isn't working. I'm still manually typing the date, the class and tooltip

Comment: the code works, you just have to modify your HTML to have all buttons with identical class identifiers, or in your actual HTML you could use the btn class but think about the next time you add a button in your page with a btn class...
here is the updated version : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bXdraG

Comment: Now it's okay! Thanks you a lot! And how can I change ```title``` with JS code?